# How do I add a new element to a list inside a python file with Python

Tags: python, list, append

`accidents=[a, b, c]` inside the `data.py` file

```
from data import accidents

def AddData()
    accidents.append(d)
    print(accidents) #this worked

print(accidents) #it didn't work
```

`data.py` file is unchanged
I want to change file `data.py`

Comment: What exactly is the question? Aren't you already `.append()`-ing to it?

Comment: Files don't change when you update variables read from them. You have to write the result back to the file. Normally you use data files for this (e.g. pickle, JSON, CSV), not python modules, since you'll have to write it back with all the python syntax for assigning the variable.

Comment: Just to mention that `accidents=[a, b, c]` is not valid syntax, unless `a`, `b` and `c` are defined before `accidents`. Nor is `accidents.append(d)` because `d` is not defined

Comment: there is no *list in the file*. the file contains *source code*. this is crucial to understand. the source code will be executed and will create various objects, but modifying those objects *doesn't modify the source code*. How could it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try adding the function to addData inside data.py instead

data.py:

```
accidents = ["a","b","c"]

Def addData(d):
    accidents.append(d)
```

other.py:

```
from data import accidents, addData

addData("d")
print(accidents)
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't actually be able to 'modify' the list in the other Python file besides when your program is running. Modifying variables will not change the actual contents of other `.py` files.

If your `accidents` array is `[1, 2, 3]` and you append to it to make it `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, when you run your program a second time, `accidents` will still start as `[1, 2, 3]`. If you want your changes to be permanent, you'll need to save the array to a file after your program terminates, and read it in when the program starts.

Something like this:

```
# Your main program

# Load your external file containing the accidents list
with open("accidents.json", 'r') as file:
    accidents = json.load(file)  # Save contents to accidents list

# Use this function to add your data
def add_data(d):
    accidents.append(d)

add_data("example")  # Add some example data

# Save your changes to the external file
with open("accidents.json", 'w') as file:
    json.dump(accidents, file)
```